# ionic 2 - set a type for the searchbar

Tags: ionic2

I have a searchbar in my app, which I'm using to filter an email list. Therefore, I want its input type to be email (because then, on a mobile device the keyboard will have @ key by default).

I've searched the documentation and saw that there is a type property on the searchbar. However, neither of the code snippets below did change the input type

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="email" (ionInput)="getContacts($event)" type="email" placeholder="email"></ion-searchbar>  

<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="email" (ionInput)="getContacts($event)" [type]="email" placeholder="email"></ion-searchbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that this is a bug relating Ionic 2, since beta9:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/7744

Also, the correct way to set type is not through input binding, therefore `type="email"` will do the trick (after the bug is solved).